# go http.Request.Conn.ActiveConn is a map, so will it have concurrent map problem?

Tags: go

go http.Request.Context.ActiveConn is a map, will it have concurrent map problem?

If there are many connections, I print the `request.Context` which is including a `ActiveConn(map)`, will it have concurrent reading and writing map problem?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "r.ctx: %#v, %+v", r.Context(), r.Context())
    })
    http.ListenAndServe(":1234", nil)
}
```

I use a webench to give a pressure test, it will fail because of concurrent map problem. So, is there any one who has the same problem? Because of this, I messed up the core service... ...

Comment: You're looking at the un-exported `activeConn` field of the `*http.Server`. Reading that field using reflection to bypass any synchronization of course is not going to be properly synchronized.

Answer (score 1):

The whole purpose of Go's http server implementation is to handle concurrent connections, so I doubt you'll see concurrency issues in the implementation itself.

What's happening here is that when printing the whole `r.Context()` there, you end up accessing an internal field of Go's `Server` object without synchronizing access to it.

That causes the `concurrent map read and map write` error you end up seeing.

Simplest solution would be to replace this:

```
fmt.Fprintf(w, "r.ctx: %#v, %+v", r.Context(), r.Context())
```

With some custom function you write that takes that `Context` object and extracts the values that are relevant for you (like for example, any custom key/value you have added yourself to the Context).

**More detailed explanation about that activeConn field**

The `activeConn` you see when you print the whole `r.Context()` as doing there, comes from Go's `Server` type.

When preparing to listen for connections, the `Server` creates a base context in which it adds a reference to the `Server` itself:

https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/net/http/server.go#L2894

```
func (srv *Server) Serve(l net.Listener) error {
    ....
    ctx := context.WithValue(baseCtx, ServerContextKey, srv)
    ....
}
```

So when printing the whole context, you end up printing that `activeConn` field:

https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/net/http/server.go#L2582

```
activeConn map[*conn]struct{}
```

The `Server` implementation synchronizes access to that map when it needs to use it, for example here:

https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/net/http/server.go#L2997

```
...

s.mu.Lock()
defer s.mu.Unlock()
if s.activeConn == nil {
    s.activeConn = make(map[*conn]struct{})
}

if add {
    s.activeConn[c] = struct{}{}
} else {
    delete(s.activeConn, c)
}
....
```

Comment: I, personally, disagree with your message, that it's a user's responsibility to do extra things just to print some value, especially when it already satisfied `String` interface. So, it really looks like a bug. I've tested simple handler, which does `fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s", r.Context())` with `ab -c100 -n1000 ...` and it fails. I'm pretty sure, than it is undefined and "undesired" behavior.

Comment: @tacobot: The only thing here that seems somewhat "bug like" is that a user can read unexported fields with reflection, but that is a design decision at that can't be changed at this point. If you're going to read the unexported internals of a structure, bypassing any synchronization methods, it's sort of on you to determine if that's OK.

Comment: @Jimb agree! But, it's a bad design decision in it's guts. Just my opinion.

Comment: @tacobot, my answer points to the cause of the issue and how to solve it (and also explains that it is not a concurrency issue in Go's http implementation itself but rather caused by printing the context), if that's a bug or not is outside the scope of this question. It can be reported to Go's project if need be.

Comment: Hi， is there any Static Detection Tool which could help me to find map problem before deploying?

Comment: @张todd, I don't think a static tool would detect this, but you can run your tests with "race detector" enabled: https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html , so one way would be for you to create a test that calls your handler concurrently and run it with race detection enabled